# TimeoutException - How to combine WebDriverWait with row.find_elements_by_xpath(?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wish to scrape star rating from this URL: https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies by using selenium.

While all the codes are fine, a TimeoutException is thrown
and I plan to solve this problem by using ***wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located***, but I have not idea who to combine it with **row.find_elements_by_xpath**
How can I do this?

```
##These are basic setups
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

'''Create new instance of Chrome in Incognito mode'''
##Adding the incognito argument to our webdriver
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(" — incognito")
##create a new instance of Chrome
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/w97802/chromedriver')

'''Scrape Basic Info'''
from parsel import Selector
url = 'https://seedly.sg/reviews/p2p-lending/funding-societies'
browser.get(url)
selector = Selector(text=browser.page_source)

####################################################################
##This is the code to get stars ratings 
'''Count stars for all pages'''
star_count_list = []

for i in range(0,16):
    sleep(2)
    ratingcolumn = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"qr0ren-7 euifNX")]')
    for row in ratingcolumn:
        star_count = 0
        try:
            stars = row.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span/span/span[contains(@style,"width:100%")]')
            sleep(20)
        except TimeoutException:
            pass
        for targets in stars:
            star_count += 1
        star_count_list.append(star_count)
    '''Automation of getting to the next page'''
    sleep(10)
    WebDriverWait(browser, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="__next"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/ul/div/div/ul/li[11]'))).click()
    sleep(8)
    print("going to the next page")

'''Print Stars Result''' 
for i,e in enumerate(star_count_list, start=1):
        print ('\n \n \n ' + str(i) + '. \n', e)
```

Answer (score 0):

get a list of elements and wait for each to be present:

```
for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
```